# In Perl, how should I populate this multilevel hash?

Tags: perl, hashtable

I am trying to find Perl's best approach for populating a multilevel hash taking into account missing keys.
So I am using this:

```
if( !exists $customer_data{$customer_id} ) {  
     $customer_data{$customer_id} = {};    
}    
$customer_data{$customer_id}->{$salesman_name} //={};
$customer_data{$customer_id}->{$salesman_name}->{$timestamp} = 1;
```

Which is weird because I am using `exists` and the `//=` thingy but I am not sure how I can write this code properly and succinctly.
Result is something like:

```
'1000' => {                                                                                             
    'jsmith' => {                                                                              
         1502121730 => 1,                                                           
         1512321730 => 1                                                        
     }                                                                              
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [autovivification](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification/) in [perldoc perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

```
$customer_data{$customer_id}{$salesperson_name}{$timestamp} = 1;
```

is sufficient.

Also, you probably do not want gendered variable names.

Comment: Actually I was trying to avoid `autovification` but I am probably confused about that. When is that bad?

Comment: @Jim  It's (potentially and probably) bad when you _look up_ (or use) non-existing nested keys/values.  Like `if ($rh{no_key}{other})` -- since it then creates the whole structure (in order to be able to look up that last part which is being checked), what one presumably doesn't want.  But in this case you _assign_ to that key, so you _are_ doing by hand what autovivification does, as Sinan's post says.

Comment: @Jim To suppress this see [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/autovivification-0.17/lib/autovivification.pm) module (pragma).  But please read up on it.